# Недопустимое имя объекта "UsersInfo"

Tags: sql-server

Есть процедура в бд. Когда я ее вызываю, возникает ошибка `Недопустимое имя объекта "UsersInfo"`. Почему?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Users_getUserbyEmail
@Email NCHAR(50)
AS 
  SELECT Id, NickName, FirstName, SecondName FROM UsersInfo WHERE Email = @Email 
  RETURN
GO
```

Comment: Видимо потому, что таблица `UsersInfo` не существует.

Comment: @kff видимо я совсем ослеп

Comment: какой sql-server используете?

Comment: Уточню комментарий @kff: таблица UsersInfo не существует в той базе, в которой выполняется данный скрипт.